# How to run background Quartz process without blocking other methods in main

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have background Quartz process to send mail every minute

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddQuartz(q =>
                {
                    
                    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();

                    
                    var jobKey = new JobKey("MailSendJob");

                    
                    q.AddJob<EmailSender>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));

                    
                    q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
                        .ForJob(jobKey) 
                        .WithIdentity("MailSendJob-trigger") 
                        .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?")); 
                });

                

                services.AddQuartzHostedService(
                    q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

                
            });
```

when I call it in main it blocks all next methods, for example `BotOnMessage().Wait()` that never executed. How to solve this issue in order to run this service in background not blocking other methods

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    GetExcelFile GF = new GetExcelFile();
                    GF.getData();    
                    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                    BotOnMessage().Wait();  //this method never executed                 
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

here is my EmailSender class

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class EmailSender : IJob
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"ExcelFiles\", "testFile.xlsx");
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@gmail.com")) 
            {
                message.Subject = "News";
                message.Body = "test Text";
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path); 
                message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                {
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 465,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "testPass")
                })
                {
                    await client.SendMailAsync(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems you did not trigger the job for the execution.

Comment: @Batuhan any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting `false` to `WaitForJobsToComplete` property ?

```cs
...
services.AddQuartzHostedService(
   q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
});
```

Comment: didn't work, BotOnMessage().Wait(); still not executed

Comment: Can you share `EmailSender` class ?

Comment: added EmailSender class in description

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to separate **build** from **run** ?
Like so:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
BotOnMessage().Wait();
host.Run();
```